# Posso criar um metodo search para arrays ou ja existe esse metodo para arrays?

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de saber se tem algum problema se eu adicionar esse metodo para arrays em javascript, e se possível como faco isso mesmo? É algo assim?

```
Array.prototype.search = function () {};
```

Comment: Podes explicar o que esse método deve fazer, caso as respostas não acertem com o que procuras?

Comment: Era justamente verificar se uma array esta guardando um certo valor ou não.

Comment: ok, nesse caso ambos os métodos que indiquei o fazem. O mais semântico talvez seja o `.includes` pois retorna simplesmente `true|false` caso a array guarde esse valor ou não.

Comment: obrigado pelas respostas, antes eu tinha que fazer um loop for maluco, agora facilitou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois métodos com funcionalidade que pode ser a que procuras:

- o método [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (ES5) que procura por uma condição e retorna o primeiro elemento que cumprir essa condição.
- o método [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (ES6) que procura por um elemento e retorna `true|false`, ao estilo do que se fazia "antes" com `.indexOf(el) != -1`.

Tendo dito isso, um método com o nome `search` não existe.

Para implementar métodos no prototype podes definir uma função onde o `this` será a array onde queres usar o método. Por exemplo para o método `.includes` existe um polyfill para browsers antigos, [bem complexo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) pois o método tem um segundo argumento para iniciar a busca a partir de um dado index.

Mas que pode implementar-se de maneira simplista, só para saber se dado elemento está numa array ou não, assim:

```js
Array.prototype.search = function(el){
  return this.indexOf(el) != -1;
}

var respostaA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].search(3);
var respostaB = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].search(6);

console.log(respostaA); // true
console.log(respostaB); // false
```